# How to reorder the data from firebase real time database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to reorder data in a recyclerview using drag and drop gestures, but do not know how to re order the data in the firebase database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase is not designed to be ordered based on some visible index, but rather on entries in the database [when queried](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data).

`orderByChild`, `orderByKey`, or `orderByValue`

So if you want to reorder the values in Firebase, you should give each item an 'index' value and call `orderByValue('index')`

---

A few lines of code can upgrade current database items to use this index:

```
int index = 0;
mDatabase.child("data").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

        // A new comment has been added, add it to the displayed list
        Data data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
        index++;
        Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
        childUpdates.put("/data/" + dataSnapshot.getKey()+"/index", index);
        mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
    }
```

Comment: ok. How would i be able to go iterate through each element in the database and change their value by index?

Comment: You can `update` your database items to include another field.

Comment: true but how would i iterate through each of the elements can you provide some code?

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample class. It will need to be modified for your specific database structure.